# what is the difference between df.drop(inplace=True) and df = df.drop()?

Tags: pandas

I usually use below two types of code to drop columns in pandas.

```
df = df.drop([columns], axis=1)
# or 
df.drop([columns], axis=1, inplace=True)
```

the result is perfectly same, but I'm curious

which one spent lesser memory&CPU and why?

Comment: there is no difference... but first copy data and change it then return, so it use more memory and a bit cpu for copy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. *df.dropna(inplace=true)*

If you set inplace = True , the dropna method will modify your DataFrame directly. That means that if you set inplace = True , dropna will drop all missing values from your original dataset.

2. *df = df.dropna()*

Remove all rows wit NULL values from the DataFrame.
df.dropna() returns the indropped rows which are saved to the main df

Hope this helps to some extent. :)